# Read and respond to android notification action link

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I'm curious to know how I can read the action link behind buttons of notifications of other apps? Basically, I want to give my app permission to read notifications, and respond to notifications sent by another app. I noticed IFTTT has a way to read the title and message of a notification, but it does not provide access to the link behind an action button.

Would anyone know how to access this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that's possible - actions basically wrap a `PendingIntent` which the system delivers when the action is taken. For security reasons, this is always recommended to be an *explicit intent*, i.e. one that gets sent to a particular component (usually something in the app that created the notification), instead of being broadcast to anything that claims to be able to / wants to handle it. [The documentation page repeats this over and over](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent) so security and preventing the wrong app from accessing these `PendingIntent`s and their data is obviously a concern.

It also says this, about explicitly passing `PendingIntent`s to other apps:

> By giving a PendingIntent to another application, **you are granting it the right to perform the operation you have specified as if the other application was yourself (with the same permissions and identity)**. As such, you should be careful about how you build the PendingIntent: almost always, for example, the base Intent you supply should have the component name explicitly set to one of your own components, to ensure it is ultimately sent there and nowhere else.

So access to `PendingIntent`s carries some implications, and I feel like it's unlikely the system allows random apps to access these, fire them off etc.